# How to split a big dataframe into individual dataframe?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, split, subset

I have a data frame which I want to split into individual data frames based on the condition that difference between values in a column is equal to 1 and column length of each variable to be greater than 30. I tried using split function with cumsum. It gives an output, which is a list.I'm not able to extract a particular dataframe with length of 'a' greater than 30 But is there anyway to get individual dataframes with length greater than 30?

```
IS_new pseq   a
15  0.5098    Q  15
16  0.5055    G  16
17  0.5807    S  17
18  0.6427    L  18
19  0.7209    T  19
20  0.6906    S  20
21  0.7629    S  21
22  0.7629    T  22
23  0.8279    T  23
```

....... 150 more such entries

For example These are 3 of 18 dataframes within the list. Now I want to only pull out dataframe which have length of a greater than 30. 
This is a practice dataframe which I'm working with. I need to replicate similar thing on a very huge dataframe.

```
$`0`
    IS_new pseq   a
15  0.5098    Q  15
16  0.5055    G  16
17  0.5807    S  17
18  0.6427    L  18
19  0.7209    T  19
20  0.6906    S  20
21  0.7629    S  21
22  0.7629    T  22
23  0.8279    T  23
24  0.8493    T  24
25  0.8853    T  25
26  0.7982    S  26
27  0.7718    S  27
28  0.7415    P  28
29  0.7881    G  29
30  0.7120    A  30
31  0.7209    G  31
32  0.7209    S  32
33  0.6227    S  33
34  0.5533    S  34
35  0.5493    P  35
36  0.5620    W  36
37  0.5017    A  37


$`1`
   IS_new pseq  a
38 0.5098    A 38

$`2`
   IS_new pseq  a
41 0.5211    N 41
58 0.5665    A 58
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by "column length of each variable to be greater than 30" . Can you show us an example of how you would want the spits done (maybe reducing the length to 5 for convenience/brevity)

Comment: Can you also show the code of what have you tried with `split` ?

Comment: a1<- c(0,cumsum(abs(diff(df$a))> 1))
aw<-split(df,a1)                                                                                                                    df is the dataframe and a is the variable above

Comment: do you want to select the elements of the split list with >= 30 rows?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes. The list contains dataframes with consecutive elements(I used cumsum and split on the main data frame to get that list) I want only those dataframes out which have each column of length> 30